# How to add filter by year and month together using dropdown on static blog website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am working on one static blog article website where I want to add 'filter by year and month' functionality, so that user can easily filter blog articles as per their needs.

I have already made a 'filter by month' feature, but then I don't know what to do when someone wants to see blog article of a specific month of a specific year, let's say December 2019 only. So, in that case I do need help.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#monthselectore').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "All") {
      $('.filterDiv').show();
      return;
    } else {
      $('.filterDiv').hide();
    }
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2 class="filterTitle">Filter by month</h2>
      <select class="form-control" id="monthselectore">
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="jan">Jan</option>
        <option value="feb">Feb</option>
        <option value="mar">Mar</option>
        <option value="apr">Apr</option>
        <option value="may">May</option>
        <option value="jun">Jun</option>
        <option value="jul">Jul</option>
        <option value="aug">Aug</option>
        <option value="sep">Sep</option>
        <option value="oct">Oct</option>
        <option value="nov">Nov</option>
        <option value="dec">Dec</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv jan"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv feb"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv mar"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv apr"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv may"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv jun"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv jul"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv aug"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv sep"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv oct"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv nov"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv dec"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this work for multiple filters you can use a similar pattern to that which you've already created, ie. using the value of the selected `option` as the `class` to filter elements by. To add years to this you can get the value of multiple `select` and concatenate them together by `.` to make a selector string which you can use to show/hide the relevant elements. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $divs = $('.filterDiv');

  $('.filter').change(function() {
    var filterSelector = $('.filter').map((i, el) => el.value ? el.value : null).get().join('.');
    $divs.hide();
    if (filterSelector) {
      $('.' + filterSelector).show();
    } else {
      $('.filterDiv').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2 class="filterTitle">Filter by month</h2>
      <select class="form-control filter" id="monthselectore">
        <option value="">All months</option>
        <option value="jan">Jan</option>
        <option value="feb">Feb</option>
        <option value="mar">Mar</option>
        <option value="apr">Apr</option>
        <option value="may">May</option>
        <option value="jun">Jun</option>
        <option value="jul">Jul</option>
        <option value="aug">Aug</option>
        <option value="sep">Sep</option>
        <option value="oct">Oct</option>
        <option value="nov">Nov</option>
        <option value="dec">Dec</option>
      </select>
      <select class="form-control filter" id="monthselectore">
        <option value="">All years</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv jan 2018">Jan 18</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv feb 2018">Feb 18</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv mar 2018">Mar 18</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv apr 2018">Apr 18</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv may 2018">May 18</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv jun 2018">Jun 18</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv jul 2018">Jul 18</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv aug 2018">Aug 18</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv sep 2018">Sep 18</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv oct 2018">Oct 18</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv nov 2018">Nov 18</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv dec 2018">Dec 18</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv jan 2019">Jan 19</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv feb 2019">Feb 19</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv mar 2019">Mar 19</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv apr 2019">Apr 19</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv may 2019">May 19</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv jun 2019">Jun 19</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv jul 2019">Jul 19</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv aug 2019">Aug 19</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv sep 2019">Sep 19</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv oct 2019">Oct 19</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv nov 2019">Nov 19</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 simpleCart_shelfItem product-item media_outer filterDiv dec 2019">Dec 19</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this solution is perfect for me, although it is showing nothing untill someone selects something from the dropdown. So, show all is not working by default. Can you please help me in this ?

Comment: That sounds like it's possible a CSS problem on your end, as you can see from the example that all `div` are visible on load

Comment: spot on man, it was indeed a css problem. Thanks for your quick response

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped